# How to differentiate Snowflake unistore table in information schema?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a table with "create hybrid table" and I expected to be able to tell the difference between this table and regular tables by querying information_schema.tables, but I do not see anything that would allow me to tell the difference. Is there a method or new view that I can use to find this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for column *is_hybrid* in SHOW TABLES. I would expect a similarly named column in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.

[image: SHOW TABLES]

Comment: I do see the column in SHOW TABLES, and though I also expected to find a similar column in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, it is certainly not there.